# symbology with 2 fields - one for the color and another for the shape?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, symbology, color

for example, i have two fields:
1 - a, b, c
2 - X, Y, Z

and i want to do like this: a - square, b - circle, c - point
X - blue, Y - red, Z - pink

and when i have a and Y - it whould be red square.

Answer (score 2):

In layer properties go to **Symbology** tab. Then choose **Categories** and **Unique Values, Many Fields**. Choose your both fields and add values to the table with particular symbol and color to all of your combinations.
[image]